# mutating multiple columns automatically in a df

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to auto generate interactions in a data frame from a list of columns.
I have this example ..

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

df<- nycflights13::weather
interactions <- c("hour","temp","dewp","humid","wind_dir","wind_speed")
df<- df %>% mutate (hour_temp= hour*temp, hour_dewp= hour*dewp)
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to generate all the columns automatically (e.g continue with temp*dewp, temp*humid...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get all the combinations in 'interactions' taking 2 at a time, specify the `FUN` in `combn` to `select` those columns, `transmute` the product (`*`) and bind them with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
out <- combn(interactions, 2, function(x) df %>%
       dplyr::select(x) %>%
       transmute(!! str_c(x, collapse="_"):= reduce(., `*`)),
          simplify = FALSE) %>% 
   bind_cols %>% 
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

-checking the output

```
names(out)
#[1] "origin"              "year"                "month"               "day"                 "hour"               
#[6] "temp"                "dewp"                "humid"               "wind_dir"            "wind_speed"         
#[11] "wind_gust"           "precip"              "pressure"            "visib"               "time_hour"          
#[16] "hour_temp"           "hour_dewp"           "hour_humid"          "hour_wind_dir"       "hour_wind_speed"    
#[21] "temp_dewp"           "temp_humid"          "temp_wind_dir"       "temp_wind_speed"     "dewp_humid"         
#[26] "dewp_wind_dir"       "dewp_wind_speed"     "humid_wind_dir"      "humid_wind_speed"    "wind_dir_wind_speed"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
m1 <- combn(interactions, 2)
df[paste(m1[1,], m1[2, ], sep="_")] <- lapply(asplit(m1, 2), 
       function(x) do.call(`*`, df[x]))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well with the example but when trying to use it in another bit of code I am getting  `Error in select(., x) : unused argument (x) `

Comment: @Stat.Enthus Are you using the `select` from `dplyr` or from other package.  Try `dplyr::select(x)` in case it is masked

Comment: Yes, Thanks! It was a masking problem. Thanks again.